# How to anonymously identify a user and store that information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, authentication, browser

I need a simple user identification system for the **purpose of allowing/prohibiting an action**.

This is **not a high-security requirement** and it is ok to make mistakes (eg same user will execute non-allowed action using different browsers).

To be less abstract, let's see at the StackOverflow voting and assume we want to allow **voting by public audience**, but only once.

The simplest thing that can work - is using a **cookie**: set a new cookie per answer; store all votes in one cookie (or combine these somehow).

This is a bit unreliable due to the **limitations of a cookie size/number**. It will also sent the cookie to the site all the time, while it is only required on 1 action.

So from this perspective I would like to avoid using cookie.
But don't see a better of doing this over a regular HTTP. I don't consider IP/MAC address etc.

So, with the context above, the questions is: how to anonymously identify a user and store that information on the client?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any other way than cookies. Session ids and the like obviously won't work. You can however use a heuristic which identifies the browser, ip, as much information as you can get to see, whether the user is unique. But this will probably fail for environments like Uni labs or other places with the shared IPs and same software base.

Comment: I tested this theory recently, and even with a shared software base the amount of uniquely identifiable data for fingerprinting was suprising. Mine was a test for the DoD - I'd be interested in others that may have controlled enviornments to duplicate. It would go great for my Master's thesis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anonymous user identification can certainly be done (and is being done) with a fairly high degree of accuracy. Rather than reprint the methodology here's a bit of reading that will lay it all out.

First is an old bit by the EFF regarding the mathmatics of user privacy (specifically the entropy behind your data) on the internet. Certainly optional, but it expresses the model that we're looking at. You can skip this if the math behind identification doesn't interest you.

http://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/01/primer-information-theory-and-privacy

Basically taken in a nutshell: using just the browser-agent, IP address and other data published in one of their examples (panopticlick) http://panopticlick.eff.org/ you have a very high likelihood of uniquely identifying a user (as long as it is the same machine) without the need for cookies. Additional information regarding their research into browser detection and uniqueness is available here:

http://panopticlick.eff.org/browser-uniqueness.pdf

Visit the panopticlick page and give it a test. It will show you what to look for (and give examples and source of how to go about it) while the .pdf will detail the uniqueness and specifics of the fingerprinting method.

My system configuration, for example, is unique among the 1,301,578 total tested with 20.38 bits of identifying information (reduction of entropy). Given their research, you will have an accuracy of 94.2% and 99.1% in identifying users between visits without the use of any client side tracking.

Comment: Good piece of information, Thanks. But how would you go about *storing* that information on the client?

Comment: I missed that last sentence of the question and I'd have to ask what the requirement for storing on the client is. With browser fingerprinting you store the information at the server end and it is completely transparent/anonymous to the client.

Comment: Hmm. That's another approach. Storing that information on the server should do the job indeed. I just did not want to 'pollute' server data with client information. But definitely what you suggest should do the job nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Store a small unique identifier on the client side as a cookie, then use that identifier to look up whatever related session data you need on your server's side.

Comment: Isn't it what I was talking about in the question?? Don't get what it answers.

Comment: Your argument was about cookie size, thus this works around sending a lot of data in the cookie.  Instead of sending a lot of data, you're sending a small amount of data.  Perhaps you need to rephrase the question.

Comment: How can you send small amount of data to for unknown number of piecies of information: store in cookie ID of all answers voted by a user. Didn't my original example provide enough context?

Comment: That's not what I said.  Store one single ID in a cookie that represents the user.  You will never add more than one ID to their cookie.  That ID can be referenced on your server to any number of ratings they've rated there.  You clearly are unfamiliar with a basic concept of sessions.

Comment: As I explained in the question, there is NO user. There is no authentication, The voting is anonymous. So you cannot store a user id just because there is no such.

Comment: I was not telling you to store a user ID, I'm telling you to generate a unique temporary ID such as a UUID or some other uniquely generated value.  If the visitor has a cookie with a UUID then you can identify them anonymously.  If they don't have that cookie, then give them one, and you can identify them for future page visits.

Answer (score 1):

MAC address would be awesome, but not possible over HTTP unfortunately (and a good thing for user privacy).

Cookie and IP address are your only options.

You can delete the cookie when you're done with it, only have it apply to the path that is relevant, or just have it expire in a few hours/days whatever is appropriate.